# How can I change the location of my ip address to specific citiies/places when browsing?

Tags: ip-address

I am based in Europe and I would like to test my website as if I am located in New York.
I have some specific features that will be visible based on cities.

Comment: Also this is not about anonymous browsing.

Comment: I think you yourself don't understand what people are telling you. No offense, but the reason for existence of VPNs and Proxies isn't only to allow anonymous browsing. Actually: That's the least important reason why they exist. Everyone gave you **right solution already**: Use VPN or Proxy. This will change where server can "see" you from. **You cannot change the location of IP** but you CAN change the IP ITSELF! So if you want to test your website as if you'd be located in other city - **use proxy that's located in that city**.

Comment: Nice One MarcinWolny for explaining...

Comment: Imageree if you don't like the VPN method then I suggest you hope over to stackoverflow and ask how you can edit your website to detect you as the administrator and tell it that you are located in this region and that region etc. As an administrator you should be able to do this, unless your website is poorly made.. no offence.

Comment: <fun>Ask people from NY on http://fiverr.com/ to let you surf your site via remote maintenance.</fun>

Comment: Suggesting you to go for the ipmask.us or a software that will mask your Current City ip. In the Software, you have option the option to change the city.

Answer (score 5):

You have a few solid options that will return results in Google and display the site as you were actually in their country. The most common methods are Proxies and VPN (Virtual Private Network) This are available as free or paid, paid services tend to be fast and not very noticeable your using a server to connect to the desired site. While a Free Service is normally painfully slow at times and especially noticeable when downloading or watching videos on such sites as YouTube.

**VPN VS PROXIES**

I won't go into every plus and negative about both but what you should know is that VPN tends to be much more secure than proxies due to encryption and the authentication system works.

There are a few free proxies and vpn's such as Zend2 and VPN Book.

Answer (score 2):

Based on how you implemented it you could set up a local proxy (or even re-configure your local webserver) to explicitely send X_FORWARDED_FOR headers with specific IPs related to NY.

Answer (score 1):

There's are VPN's you can use. HMA VPN and Overplay are a couple you could get for like 10 bucks per month.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of applicable resources to test this without the need of installing a proxy, VPN or something else, like [Webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org), slow but working with good information.